# Setting the form.invalid property to true from a HTML select element in Angular 2

Tags: html, forms, validation, angular

I have created a basic form that contains various input elements (mainly text) all of the text boxes have the 'Required' attribute set plus a simple regex pattern. Using Angular 2's Form directive I am disabling a button if the field text inputs are empty or the regex is not met. This works as expected. However,  thrown into the mix is a 'Select' element with 2 'Option' child elements. The first is my default and the second my data bound list. I would like to set the form.invalid property to true if the initial:

```
<option value="default">Select a department...</option>
```

is selected from the combo box.

My issue as it stands is that if I enter valid data into all of my text boxes but leave the combo box as 'Select a department...' the form.invalid property is false and the button is enabled. As 'Select a department...'
is not a valid value I need the button to become disabled if that is selected?

Current HTML select code as it stands

```
    <form class="form-inline" #form="ngForm" novalidate>
      <div class="col-sm-12">          
        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="AddfirstName.invalid && AddfirstName.touched">
          <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="AddfirstName">First Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input class="form-control" #AddfirstName="ngModel" required pattern="\D+" placeholder="First Name" [ngModel]="firstName" (ngModelChange)="firstLetterOfFirstNameToUpperCase($event)"
              name="firstName">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="AddfirstName.invalid && AddfirstName.touched ">First Name Is mandatory and cannot contain numbers</div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="AddlastName.invalid && AddlastName.touched">
          <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="AddlastName">Last Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input class="form-control" #AddlastName="ngModel" required pattern="\D+" placeholder="Last Name" [ngModel]="lastName" (ngModelChange)="firstLetterOfLastNameToUpperCase($event)"
              name="lastName" />
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="AddlastName.invalid && AddlastName.touched ">Last Name Is mandatory and cannot contain numbers </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="AdduserName.invalid && AdduserName.touched">
          <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="AdduserName">User Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input class="form-control" #AdduserName="ngModel" required placeholder="User Name" ngModel name="userName" />
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="AdduserName.invalid && AdduserName.touched">User Name Is mandatory</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"[class.has-error]="Addpassword.invalid && Addpassword.touched">
          <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="Addpassword">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" #Addpassword="ngModel" required placeholder="Password" ngModel name="password" />
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="Addpassword.invalid && Addpassword.touched ">Password Is mandatory</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="hasDepartmentError">
          <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="Department">Department:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" id="Department" #AddDepartment="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="addDepartment"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            (change)="validateDepartment(AddDepartment.value)"  
            (blur)="validateDepartment(AddDepartment.value)">
            <option value="default">Select a department...</option>
             <option *ngFor="let department of departmentList">{{department.name}}</option>
          </select>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="hasDepartmentError">Department Is mandatory</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addUser(AddfirstName.value, AddlastName.value, AdduserName.value, Addpassword.value, AddDepartment.value);
        AddfirstName.value=null;AddlastName.value=null;Addpassword.value=null;AdduserName.value=null;" [disabled]="form.invalid">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
    </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have forgotten to put `required` on your select. Your two-way binding also seems to take away the default value of the drop down list, so I would loose that and just use `ngModel` instead. You really don't need to use two-way binding in forms, the form names take care of that, and when you submit the form, you have a nice object to work with.

when you loose the ngModel, you also drop the `ngModelOptions` and use the `name` attribute instead, which would be needed for the form.

I'm also unsure about the `validateDepartment` method. You wouldn't need it, as you can validate this in the template.

So all in all the final snippet of your select could look like this:

```
<select required #addDepartment="ngModel" name="addDepartment" ngModel>
  <option value="">Select a department...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let department of departmentList">{{department.name}}</option>
</select> 

<div *ngIf="addDepartment.errors?.required">
  Department required!
</div>
```

Here's a

### [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JNapNzJ0Ztc9r5kbbFXM?p=preview)

to play with, where you can also see the object created from the form! :)

Comment: Thanks AJT_82, your solution pretty much got me all the way to my resolution. I use the validate department method to set the hasDepartmentError flag which used to display my alert alert-danger class div as and when needed.The only only extra thing i needed to do was extend the button element as such: [disabled]="form.invalid || hasDepartmentError this ensured that if the user selected a valid option   then and invalid one the button become disabled. Many thanks.

Comment: Well great that you came to a solution! And nice if I could help you along the way to get there :) Have great day/evening/night/morning (depending on your timezone, hehhe) and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the value from your first option and mark your select required:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Department" #AddDepartment="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="addDepartment"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        (change)="validateDepartment(AddDepartment.value)"  
        (blur)="validateDepartment(AddDepartment.value)"
        required>
        <option>Select a department...</option>
         <option *ngFor="let department of departmentList">{{department.name}}</option>
      </select>
```